# Finding characteristic function and differentiate to get expectation

Tags: characteristic-functions

I was asked to find the characteristic function of a pdf and differentiate it to get the expectation.

$p(x) = xe^{-x}$   for $x \ge 0$

I am doing this in the following way. Sorry that i don't know how to insert the correct symbol....

$$ϕw = \int_0^\infty e^{itx} x e^{-x}  dx$$

$$ = \int_0^\infty e^{itx-x} x   dx$$

Then exponent $ = -x(1-it)$

and let $ z = -x(1-it)$

with $dz/dx = -(1-it)$

Then we will have

$$ϕw = \int_0^\infty (\frac{z}{1-it})(e^z)(\frac{1}{1-it}) dz$$

$$ = \frac{1}{(1-it)^2}\int_0^\infty  z e^zdz$$

$$ = \frac{1}{(1-it)^2} $$

Then i differentiate the above and i will get zero which make me not so sure about my answer. Can anyone have a look of my step above to see if i got enough mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\phi_X(t)=E(e^{itX})$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\phi_X(t))=E(iXe^{itX})$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\phi_X(0))=E(iX)=iE(X)$$
In other words, you found $\phi_X(t)$ correctly, but we must differentiate with respect to $t$ to find expectation. In your case we have:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(\phi_X(t))=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg(\frac{1}{(1-it)^2}\Bigg)$$
$$=\frac{2i}{(1-it)^3}$$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}(\phi_X(0)) = 2 i=iE(X)$$
$$\therefore E(x)=2$$